# Swift Mailer ruins autolading

Tags: php, autoload, swiftmailer, autoloader

I'm writing simple PHP application which is using [Swift Mailer library](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/including-the-files.html). My app doesn't use namespaces nor composer.

However, after requiring `swift_required.php` my (model) classes are not found (*Fatal error: Class 'Format' not found* is thrown by PHP interpret).

**Autolading**

```
define("_DOCUMENT_ROOT", str_replace("//", "/", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/"));
    function __autoload($class_name) {
        $file_name = $class_name . '.php';
        $include_foleder = array("php/model/", "templates/","cron/crons_tasks/");
        foreach ($include_foleder as $folder) {
            $abs_path = _DOCUMENT_ROOT . $folder . $file_name;
            if (file_exists($abs_path)) {
                require_once $abs_path;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problematic part of function**

```
  $bar = Format::bar($foo); //works fine
  require_once _DOCUMENT_ROOT . "php/lib/swiftmailer-master/lib/swift_required.php"; //works fine
  $bar = Format::bar($foo); //Class not found
```

Class `Format` is my custom class, located in `_DOCUMENT_ROOT . php/model/Format.php`. Also other custom classes (from model folder) after requiring Swift Mailer are not found.

So I guessing that my former autoload is somehow overridden by Swift Mailer, is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of __autoload(), you should use spl_autoload_register.

> If there must be multiple autoload functions, spl_autoload_register()
>   allows for this. It effectively creates a queue of autoload functions,
>   and runs through each of them in the order they are defined. By
>   contrast, __autoload() may only be defined once.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

```
define("_DOCUMENT_ROOT", str_replace("//", "/", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/"));

spl_autoload_register(function($class_name) {
    $file_name = $class_name . '.php';
    $include_folder = array("php/model/", "templates/","cron/crons_tasks/");
    foreach ($include_folder as $folder) {
        $abs_path = _DOCUMENT_ROOT . $folder . $file_name;
        if (file_exists($abs_path)) {
            require_once $abs_path;
        }
    }
});
```